# Server Side Request Forgery vulnerability

Tags: java, rest, sonarqube

I have a RESTful service controller that requests another RESTful service

```
@ResponseBody
@RequestMapping(value = "/headerparameters/{instanceId}", method = RequestMethod.DELETE)
public RestContainerFormBean passivizeHeaderParameter(@PathVariable String instanceId) throws GenericException, IOException {

    String url = proactiveURL + "/customerheaders/" + instanceId;
    if(isSecurityCheckOK(url)){
        ResponseEntity<CustomerHeaderParameterBean> response = restTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.DELETE, new HttpEntity<>(new HttpHeaders()), CustomerHeaderParameterBean.class);
        CustomerHeaderParameterBean result = response.getBody();
        setButtonActivity(result);
        l10nOfValue(result);
        return new RestContainerFormBean(result);
    } else{
        throw new IOException();
    }
}
```

This code can not pass SonarQube policy.

> Refactor this code to not construct the URL from tainted,
>
> User provided data, such as URL parameters, POST data payloads, or
>   cookies, should always be considered untrusted and tainted. A remote
>   server making requests to URLs based on tainted data could enable
>   attackers to make arbitrary requests to the internal network or to the
>   local file system.
>
> The problem could be mitigated in any of the following ways:
>
> Validate the user provided data based on a whitelist and reject input
>   not matching. Redesign the application to not send requests based on
>   user provided data.

How can I pass the policy by sticking on REST conventions ?

Comment: try using UriComponentsBuilder to encode the URL instead of using raw URL.

Comment: This solves my problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use UriComponentsBuilder to encode the URL instead of using raw URL.